# Powershell, Sql and export data in loop to html

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, database, powershell

I have table in my database with following columns :

```
LOGIN | AVAILABLE | MORE INFO
```

I want to generate html's files for every unique login. Each html file should display the rows relating to a single "login". Every "login" has a different number of rows. The name of each generated file should be such as "login"
I have only a script that writes to html the entire table.

I tried to use "loop for" to generate these files, but to no avail.

This is my code:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "ConnectionString"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
$SqlCmd.Connection.Open()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select login, available, more_info from [schema].[table]"                       
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$FilePath    = "Path" + login + ".html"
$Title = " Title"
$DataSet.Tables[0]  | convertto-html -property login, available, more_info -title $Title > $FilePath
```

Comment: I tried to use "loop for" to generate these files, but to no avail... I dont know how to deal with it. Any sugestions? :)

Comment: Looks like you are pulling in 3 entire tables from SQL. Are these related? What fields are in the tables? Good start would be to process one login at a time. `foreach ($login in $DataSet.Tables[0]) {...process here...}`